# C++: How To Input Number from Right to Left (Right Justified)?

Tags: c++, cin

If you ever used an ATM machine to withdraw money, and lets say you want to withdraw $20, you input the number like this:

```
you enter 2:   00.02  
then 0 :       00.20  
then 0:        02.00  
then 0:        20.00
```

I am trying to accomplish similar thing in a C++ application using `std::cin`. How can I **right justify** the input? is it possible to do it with `cin` or do I need a different method to accomplish this?

Comment: Input is line buffered by default, meaning no input is provided until the user presses **Enter**. You need to put the terminal into raw (non-canonical) mode where the key is read with every press. That would let the user enter digits and you could update the field by overwriting with the new result after each keypress is read.

Comment: Understood, I have done something similar to what you are suggesting,

Comment: In lieu of using `tcsetattr()`, you can also use `std::cin.get()` to read a character at a time in a loop, but you will need a way of exiting the loop when input is done (like exit if any non-digit is entered after the numeric input starts). That is a way to stay in canonical mode (with backspace, etc.. provided) and still do character oriented input. Up to you.